# Accessing Two Models from Inside One ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have the need to list out some items in a view and also populate a dropdown list with data from a different model. The potential code is as follows. Am I allowed to do this? If not, how do I populate the dropdown from the other model:

```
<div ng-controller="CaseListCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="case in cases">
        <div>{case.Case_Number}</div>
        <div>
           {case.Case_Title}&nbsp;
           <select>
                <!-- AM I ALLOWED TO DO THIS? -->
                <option  ng-repeat="status in statuses">{status.Code}</option>
           </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the status in the same `$scope` ?

Comment: Use ng-options https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Hmmm...maybe you should create a model just for the view and loop through that model.

Comment: It is possible to nest ng-repeats, but in this case, I agree with @klauskpm - use ng-options.  Without ng-options, you could also consider tying the select to a data variable and populate the variable in javascript.